# Get ID of newly created record in screen flow

Tags: visual-workflow, screen-flow, record, create-records, subflow

I know there is a similar question, however it did not help me all the way through. I have a screen flow to clone a Quote record.

I use a screen flow because my Quote object is master to 4 other detail objects, and the sales team asked for a screen to select which of these detail objects they want to clone with the quote.

After the Create Records element, I need to create the child records on those 4 detail objects, and they must have a parent record: the newly created quote.

But I still have no ideia if this is possible. I need to retrieve the ID of the newly created to quote in order to create the child records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you create the record, the variable or element will have the ID of the newly created record. Stated in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_data_create.htm&type=5):

> For record variables and record collection variables, the ID field values are blank. The flow populates the ID fields after the record is created.

Also, it is noted that:

> Optionally, store the ID of the created record in a Text variable. For example, when you need the record’s ID to create child records or to provide a link to the created record.